# Can I use a 6 pin Bluetooth module in a 4 pin socket?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Funduino joystick shield and it features a 4 pin bluetooth socket in the top right hand corner (just above the `D`, `T`, `-` and `+` legends).

[image: Joystick Shield]

For some reason, on eBay, 6 pin bluetooth modules are cheaper and more common than 4 pin bluetooth modules.

[image: Bluetooth Module]

The joystick shield's 4 pin socket is labelled `R T - +`. Obviously these correspond with `RXD`, `TXD`, `GND` and `VCC` on the bluetooth module.

I was wondering:

1. What is the difference between the 4 pin and 6 pin modules?
2. Can I use a 6 pin module in the four pin socket on the joystick shield?
3. What is the function of additional `STATE` and `EN` pins on the bluetooth module?
4. Are these two additional pins necessary as other modules do not have them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What is the difference between the 4 pin and 6 pin modules?

The 6-pin modules have more pins, used for other features.

> 2. Can I use a 6 pin module in the four pin socket on the joystick shield?

I don't see why not, as long as you tie/float the other pins appropriately.

> 3. What is the function of additional STATE and EN pins on the bluetooth module?

Whatever the documentation says they do.

> 4. Are these two additional pins necessary as other modules do not have them?

Probably not. But they provide additional functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Butchering a 6 pin module down to 4 pins certainly seems to be the cheaper option.

Comment: Just poked around, and EN is connected to the voltage regulator; pulling it low will shut down the whole module. No idea what STATE does though, since it connects to a GPIO.

Answer (score 4):

After some more concerted searching I have found the answer on [Success Using the JY-MCU (linvor) Bluetooth Module](http://www.instructables.com/id/Success-Using-the-JY-MCU-linvor-Bluetooth-Module/):

> The module has 6 pins labeled on the back, but most modules only have
>   4 of those populated with pogo pins.  KEY & STATE seem to be not
>   required, as KEY is used for flashing the device and STATE simply
>   indicates if the device is awake or not.  So that leaves only GND,
>   VCC, TXD, RXD.  Not shown is Pin 11 which is the RESET pin, resetting
>   the module when pulled LOW.

So, the answer is apparently yes, and you can buy a cheaper 6 pin module and remove (snip/desolder) the two additional pins.  The `EN` pin is also apparently labelled as `KEY` on some modules.