# Funduino Joystick Shield with Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Funduino Joystick Shield (See here [Funduino on Gearbeast store](http://www.gearbest.com/boards-shields/pp_236610.html?currency=GBP&gclid=CKvOx76k0soCFUieGwodKTcD-w)) which has some Bluetooth pins.

Does anyone know what pins they are connected to, and has anyone successfully connected to a BT HC-05 device using SoftwareSerial?

Comment: See [Can I use a 6 pin Bluetooth module in a 4 pin socket?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13818/can-i-use-a-6-pin-bluetooth-module-in-a-4-pin-socket/)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turns out that the tx/rx for the board are connected to the standard pins 0 and 1 on the Arduino.
To use this, you can simply use Serial.write.
Of course, remember to take of the module when trying to upload your code.....

Comment: You don't need to remove the board when using a Atmel 32u4 based Arduino like the Leonardo.